# Proper way to match at least 1 term from a list of terms

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I need to match a field's list to see if at least one term is there from another list. In other words, my Es stored item has a list of "categories" that it fits in. I need to pass up a list of categories to include in the search. I want to get all items that have in their list of categories one or more of the categories from the list of categories I am including in the search.

I have found that this code does as I want:

```
...
  .Must(qs => qs
    .TermsSet(t => t
      .Field(tf => tf.categories)
      .Terms(searchCategories)
      .MinimumShouldMatchScript(ss => ss.Source("1"))
    )
  )
...
```

But it seems really strange to put a script of "1" in. It feels like I may be missing a more simple way to make this happen. Are my suspicions correct? Is there a better way to do this?

**Update**

The above code produces this es request:

```
...
  "must":[
    {
      "terms_set":{
        "categories":{
          "terms":[1],
          "minimum_should_match_script":{"source":"1"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
...
```

Where `terms` is the `searchCategories` list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying a source of `"1"` for the [`terms set` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-set-query.html) minimum should match script field will be the return value of the executed [Painless script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-painless.html) that determines the minimum number of terms that should match. The script can of course be more complex than returning a single value per document, allowing you to come up with more complex matching requirements for use cases such as [attribute based access control](https://www.elastic.co/blog/attribute-based-access-control-with-xpack).

If you only need *any one* term of a list of provided terms to match, then you could simply use the [`terms` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html)

```cs
var searchCategories = new [] {1 };

var searchResponse = client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
    .Query(q => +q
        .Terms(t => t
            .Field(f => f.categories)
            .Terms(searchCategories)
        )
    )
);
```

which would yield

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "categories": [
              1
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The [unary `+` overloaded operator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html#unary-plus-operator) in the query is a feature of NEST that makes writing bool queries a little more terse.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Don't know how I missed `Terms`.